# Ways of approaching the study of a Hausdorff space $X$ which has the structure of a complex manifold.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

In *Holomorphic Functions of Several Variables* by L. Kaup and B. Kaup, the authors have the following discussion in the opening of section 31, which concerns ringed spaces.

If a Hausdorff space $X$ has the structure of a complex manifold, then one can approach a characterisation of that structure in two different ways:

1. by defining a complex atlas on $X$, or
2. By distinguishing, in the sheaf $\mathscr{C}_X$ of continuous functions on $X$, a subsheaf $\mathscr{O}_X$ with the following property: each $x \in X$ admits an open neighbourhood $U \subset X$ and a homeomorphism $\varphi : U \to U' \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ that induces an isomorphism between $\mathscr{O}_X \vert_U$ and $\mathscr{O}_n \vert_{U'}$.

Note that $\mathscr{O}_n$ denotes the structure sheaf on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

I have the following questions:

1. Can we always find such a subsheaf $\mathscr{O}_X$?
2. Is this subsheaf unique with respect to the topological space $X$?
3. If the Hausdorff space $X$ has the structure of a complex manifold, why do we choose a subsheaf of $\mathscr{C}_X$ rather than a subsheaf of the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, there are many obstructions to having a complex structure, for example $X$ must be even-dimensional, it must have a smooth structure, and then given this there are various conditions on its characteristic classes that must be satisfied.
2. No, for example there are already uncountably many different complex structures on the torus $T^2$, given by elliptic curves.
3. This subsheaf *is* the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$, with respect to the complex structure that's being discussed.

Comment: Could you add some more information about the conditions on the characteristic classes, or provide a reference?

Comment: The basic condition is that its odd Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_{2k+1}$ must vanish (in particular $X$ must be orientable) and its even Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_{2k}$ must be the reduction $\bmod 2$ of integral classes $c_k$ (the Chern classes of the almost complex structure). This is probably in Milnor-Stasheff. There are other obstructions. For example, you can show that the only spheres with a complex structure are $S^2$ and possibly $S^6$ (this is an open problem).

Comment: Also, for 2) there are actually two issues. Given a sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$ wrt some complex structure you can pull back along any homeomorphism $f : X \to X$ to get another such sheaf, which will generally be different as a subsheaf of the sheaf of continuous functions even though the corresponding isomorphism class of complex manifold doesn't change. So the complex structures on $T^2$ give a counterexample to a stronger claim, about sheaves of this sort up to pullback along homeomorphisms.